# How to use vimdiff to compare the first 1000 line of two very large files (say a.txt and b.txt)

Tags: vim

As the title, 1000 lines became a little bit too much to use diff, and so `vimdiff` is the best choice. My first thought was that if `vimdiff` provide this as in-building function. If not, a walk around would be combine `vimdiff` and `head`, as a one-liner without creating two buffer files.

Comment: Are you asking how to use vimdiff in general, or how to use it in this specific use case? What exactly was the problem when you tried to use vimdiff like you would do in any other case?

Comment: vimdiff is nothing else than simply Vim. Of course, you can do everything with Vim. E.g. `:vnew`, `:read !head -1000 filename` or `:call setline(1, readfile(filename, '', 1000))`. Then `:windo diffthis` etc. etc.

Comment: Why normal diff does not work for you `diff -u <(head -n 1000 file0.txt) <(head -n 1000 file1.txt) | vim -`?

Comment: Hope to help you with https://github.com/rickhowe/spotdiff.vim. You can specify the line range to compare in vim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're running bash, you could invoke it as

```sh
$ vimdiff <(head -n 1000 "file1.txt") <(head -n 1000 "file2.txt")
```

(or `gvimdiff`). This uses [bash process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) to take a temporary named pipe holding the outputs of those `head` commands and compares them in `vimdiff`.

Those pipes' names will vary based on your system. On my Linux system, they look like `/proc/123456/fd/11` and `/proc/123456/fd/12` (where 123456 is the process ID of the parent bash shell). Note that these won't share the extensions of your original files (and you may confuse which is which; remember the leftmost was the first and the rightmost was the last—which I say because you can put in a third as well). Consider a command like `vimdiff -c 'windo set syn=bash' <(head …) <(head …)` to e.g. set both of them to use the bash format for highlighting.

If you want better labels, you could shove an echo in there, like `<(echo "file1.txt"; head …)` and it'll appear on the first line. To assign custom names to the statusline so they show up on the ruler, you could launch it like this:

```sh
$ vimdiff -c "windo setlocal statusline=$file1" <(head -n 1000 "$file1") \
                  +"setlocal statusline=$file2" <(head -n 1000 "$file2")
```

… though note that spaces in filenames won't work in the statusline (they have to be escaped rather than quoted).